# how to derive that golden rule steady state = alpha in the solow model?

Tags: macroeconomics, solow

I have successfully derived the Golden Rule steady state for capital, but I'm struggling to derive the saving rate = equal to alpha (α) for the Golden Rule level. Have I made an error in my calculations? It's worth noting that I'm assuming no technological growth in my Solow model.

derive $s_{gold}=α$

Consumption is maximised when:
$mpk=δ+n$

Production function
$f(k)=y=k^α$

$mpk=∂f(k)/∂k=αk^{(α-1)}$

$k_g=(α/(δ+n)^{(1/1-α)})$

Comment: Have considered typing "[golden rule Solow](https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=golden+rule+solow)" into the SE's search bar?